# How to fix Invalid index in ArrayList on Android

Tags: android, list, arraylist

In my application I want get some **list** from server, and show this list into **`ChipCloud`**. `ChipCloud` has **Tag** library. **Library Link :** https://github.com/adroitandroid/ChipCloud
.I write below code but when run application when click on items show me below **error** :

```
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 11, size is 6
at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:255)
at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:308)
at com.example.com.Activities.FullSearchMini$2$5.chipSelected(FullSearchMini.java:286)
at com.adroitandroid.chipcloud.ChipCloud.chipSelected(ChipCloud.java:253)
at com.adroitandroid.chipcloud.Chip.onClick(Chip.java:138)
at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4764)
at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19844)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5349)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:908)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:703)
```

**My Codes :**

```
    public class FullSearchMini extends AppCompatActivity {

    @BindView(R.id.miniFullSearch_toolbarText)
    EditText fullSearchMini_headerText;
    @BindView(R.id.fullSearchMini_celebritiesRecyclerView)
    RecyclerView fullSearchMini_celebritiesRecyclerView;
    @BindView(R.id.miniFullSearch_movieRecyclerView)
    RecyclerView miniFullSearch_movieRecyclerView;
    @BindView(R.id.miniFullSearch_SeriesRecyclerView)
    RecyclerView miniFullSearch_SeriesRecyclerView;
    @BindView(R.id.miniFullSearch_UserRecyclerView)
    RecyclerView miniFullSearch_UserRecyclerView;
    @BindViews({R.id.fullSearchMini_celebritiesHeaderLay, R.id.miniFullSearch_movieHeaderLay, R.id.miniFullSearch_SeriesHeaderLay,
            R.id.miniFullSearch_UserHeaderLay})
    List<RelativeLayout> miniSearchLayouts;
    @BindViews({R.id.celebritiesLine, R.id.moviesLine, R.id.SeriesLine})
    List<RelativeLayout> miniSearchLines;
    @BindView(R.id.fullSearchMini_didYouMeanLay)
    RelativeLayout fullSearchMini_didYouMeanLay;
    @BindView(R.id.miniFullSearch_LoadLay)
    RelativeLayout miniFullSearch_LoadLay;
    @BindView(R.id.fullSearchMini_chipCloud)
    ChipCloud fullSearchMini_chipCloud;
    @BindView(R.id.fullSearchMini_EmptyLay)
    RelativeLayout fullSearchMini_EmptyLay;
    @BindView(R.id.empty_text)
    TextView empty_text;
    @BindView(R.id.miniFullSearch_LoadProgress)
    ProgressBar miniFullSearch_LoadProgress;
    private Context context;
    private MiniSearchCelebritiesAdapter celebritiesAdapter;
    private MiniSearchMoviesAdapter moviesAdapter;
    private MiniSearchSeriesAdapter seriesAdapter;
    private MiniSearchUsersAdapter userAdapter;
    private List<Celebrity> celebritiesModel = new ArrayList<>();
    private List<Movie> moviesModel = new ArrayList<>();
    private List<Series> seriesModel = new ArrayList<>();
    private List<User> userModel = new ArrayList<>();
    private String searchKey, chipKey;
    private List<String> cloudChipList = new ArrayList<>();
    private String[] mostlyMatchedKeywordsStrings;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_mini_full_search);

        // Initialize
        ButterKnife.bind(this);
        context = this;

        //Set Color to progressBar
        miniFullSearch_LoadProgress.getIndeterminateDrawable().setColorFilter(Color.parseColor("#ff8d00"),
                android.graphics.PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);

        celebritiesAdapter = new MiniSearchCelebritiesAdapter(context, celebritiesModel);
        moviesAdapter = new MiniSearchMoviesAdapter(context, moviesModel);
        seriesAdapter = new MiniSearchSeriesAdapter(context, seriesModel);
        userAdapter = new MiniSearchUsersAdapter(context, userModel);

        initRecyclerView(fullSearchMini_celebritiesRecyclerView);
        initRecyclerView(miniFullSearch_movieRecyclerView);
        initRecyclerView(miniFullSearch_SeriesRecyclerView);
        initRecyclerView(miniFullSearch_SeriesRecyclerView);
        initRecyclerView(miniFullSearch_UserRecyclerView);

        // TextWatcher
        fullSearchMini_headerText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
                searchKey = editable.toString();
                if (searchKey.length() > 1) {
                    getData(searchKey);
                }
            }
        });
    }

    private void getData(String key) {
        FullSearchSendData sendData = new FullSearchSendData();
        sendData.setKey(key);
        sendData.setLoadImages(true);
        sendData.setSearchInCelebrities(true);
        sendData.setSearchInMovies(true);
        sendData.setSearchInSeries(true);
        sendData.setSearchInEpisodes(false);
        sendData.setSearchInUsers(true);
        sendData.setPageIndex(1);
        sendData.setPageSize(4);
        sendData.setMaxDistance(1);

        miniFullSearch_LoadLay.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        InterfaceApi api = ApiClient.getClient().create(InterfaceApi.class);
        Call<FullSearchResponse> call = api.getFullSearch(sendData);

        call.enqueue(new Callback<FullSearchResponse>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<FullSearchResponse> call, Response<FullSearchResponse> response) {
                FullSearchResponse searchResponse = response.body();
                if (searchResponse.getData().getCelebrities() != null) {
                    if (searchResponse.getData().getCelebritiesCount() > 0) {
                        celebritiesModel.clear();
                        celebritiesModel.addAll(searchResponse.getData().getCelebrities());
                        celebritiesAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        fullSearchMini_celebritiesRecyclerView.setAdapter(celebritiesAdapter);
                        miniSearchLayouts.get(0).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        miniSearchLines.get(0).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        fullSearchMini_celebritiesRecyclerView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                        miniSearchLayouts.get(0).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(View view) {
                                Intent intent = new Intent(context, FullSearch.class);
                                intent.putExtra(ExtraContains.FULL_SEARCH_TEXT.name(), searchKey);
                                startActivity(intent);
                            }
                        });
                    } else {
                        miniSearchLayouts.get(0).setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        miniSearchLines.get(0).setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        fullSearchMini_celebritiesRecyclerView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    }
                }
                if (searchResponse.getData().getMovies() != null) {
                    if (searchResponse.getData().getMoviesCount() > 0) {
                        moviesModel.clear();
                        moviesModel.addAll(searchResponse.getData().getMovies());
                        moviesAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        miniFullSearch_movieRecyclerView.setAdapter(moviesAdapter);
                        miniSearchLayouts.get(1).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        miniSearchLines.get(1).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        miniFullSearch_movieRecyclerView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                        miniSearchLayouts.get(1).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(View view) {
                                Intent intent = new Intent(context, FullSearch.class);
                                intent.putExtra(ExtraContains.FULL_SEARCH_TEXT.name(), searchKey);
                                startActivity(intent);
                            }
                        });
                    } else {
                        miniSearchLayouts.get(1).setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        miniSearchLines.get(1).setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        miniFullSearch_movieRecyclerView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    }
                }
                if (searchResponse.getData().getSeries() != null) {
                    if (searchResponse.getData().getSeriesCount() > 0) {
                        seriesModel.clear();
                        seriesModel.addAll(searchResponse.getData().getSeries());
                        seriesAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        miniFullSearch_SeriesRecyclerView.setAdapter(seriesAdapter);
                        miniSearchLayouts.get(2).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        miniSearchLines.get(2).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        miniFullSearch_SeriesRecyclerView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                        miniSearchLayouts.get(2).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(View view) {
                                Intent intent = new Intent(context, FullSearch.class);
                                intent.putExtra(ExtraContains.FULL_SEARCH_TEXT.name(), searchKey);
                                startActivity(intent);
                            }
                        });
                    } else {
                        miniSearchLayouts.get(2).setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        miniSearchLines.get(2).setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        miniFullSearch_SeriesRecyclerView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    }
                }
                if (searchResponse.getData().getUsers() != null) {
                    if (searchResponse.getData().getUsersCount() > 0) {
                        userModel.clear();
                        userModel.addAll(searchResponse.getData().getUsers());
                        userAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        miniFullSearch_UserRecyclerView.setAdapter(userAdapter);
                        miniSearchLayouts.get(3).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        miniFullSearch_UserRecyclerView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                        miniSearchLayouts.get(3).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(View view) {
                                Intent intent = new Intent(context, FullSearch.class);
                                intent.putExtra(ExtraContains.FULL_SEARCH_TEXT.name(), searchKey);
                                startActivity(intent);
                            }
                        });
                    } else {
                        miniSearchLayouts.get(3).setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        miniFullSearch_UserRecyclerView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    }
                }

                // Did you mean
                String[] mostlyMatchedKeywordsStrings;
                mostlyMatchedKeywordsStrings = searchResponse.getData().getMostlyMatchedKeywordsText();
                cloudChipList.clear();
                for (int i = 0; i < mostlyMatchedKeywordsStrings.length; i++) {
                    cloudChipList.add(mostlyMatchedKeywordsStrings[i]);
                    if (i >= mostlyMatchedKeywordsStrings.length - 2) {
                        fullSearchMini_didYouMeanLay.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        fullSearchMini_chipCloud.addChip(mostlyMatchedKeywordsStrings[i]);

                        Log.e("searchKeys", mostlyMatchedKeywordsStrings[i]);
                    }
                }

                fullSearchMini_chipCloud.setChipListener(new ChipListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void chipSelected(int i) {
                        chipKey = cloudChipList.get(i);
                        Intent intent = new Intent(context, FullSearch.class);
                        intent.putExtra(ExtraContains.FULL_SEARCH_TEXT.name(), chipKey);
                        startActivity(intent);

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void chipDeselected(int i) {

                    }
                });

                if (searchResponse.getData().getCelebrities().size() == 0 && searchResponse.getData().getSeries().size() == 0
                        && searchResponse.getData().getMovies().size() == 0 && searchResponse.getData().getUsers().size() == 0) {
                    fullSearchMini_EmptyLay.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    empty_text.setText(context.getResources().getString(R.string.noResultFound) + " for : " + searchKey);
                } else {
                    fullSearchMini_EmptyLay.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }

                miniFullSearch_LoadLay.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<FullSearchResponse> call, Throwable t) {
                miniFullSearch_LoadLay.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        });
    }

    @OnClick(R.id.miniFullSearch_toolbarBack)
    void backPress() {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }

    private void initRecyclerView(RecyclerView recyclerView) {
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(context));
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        recyclerView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);
    }
}
```

**Show me above error for this line :**

```
chipKey = cloudChipList.get(i);
```

How can I fix this error? Please help me my friend. I really need your help. please

Answer (score 0):

You are setting onChipListner on fullSearchMini_chipCloud but inside chipSelected method you are fetching that element from cloudChipList. Both fullSearchMini_chipCloud and cloudChipList have different lengths. Try to make their length equal.

This should solve your purpose

```
     for (int i = 0; i < mostlyMatchedKeywordsStrings.length; i++) {
            cloudChipList.add(mostlyMatchedKeywordsStrings[i]);
            fullSearchMini_didYouMeanLay.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            fullSearchMini_chipCloud
                  .addChip(mostlyMatchedKeywordsStrings[i]);
        }
```

Comment: can you send me code with my above codes? please my friend. please

Comment: you have used if (i >= mostlyMatchedKeywordsStrings.length - 2) condition which you need to remove aleady fullSearchMini_chipCloud is having six item you are repeatedly adding four more to it but cloudChipList is only having six items

Comment: Thanks my friend, where you use this line : `fullSearchMini_chipCloud.addChip(mostlyMatchedKeywordsStrings[i]);`

Comment: fullSearchMini_chipCloud already have 6 elements you don't need to add to. If possible show me the whole code

Comment: when code write this code : `fullSearchMini_chipCloud.addChip(mostlyMatchedKeywordsString‌​s[i]);` not show me items . can you send me your Skype ID? please :(

Comment: can you update your full java code in your question?

Comment: please see my update post. please help me. I really need your help :(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154584/discussion-between-yoyo-animate-and-shriyansh-gautam).